# Реализация цикличной карусели

Tags: javascript

Помогите пожалуйста сделать простую зацикленную карусель на JS сам в этой теме новичок, алгоритм действий вроде как понятен но в редакторе написать код не могу...
Нужно что бы по клику на кнопки менялись местами карточки.

```css
.page-main__block-products {
  margin: 0 0 0 0;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  display: flex;
}

.page-main__controls {
  width: 142px;
  height: 59px;
  margin-top: 40px;
  margin-right: 30px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0px 10px 46px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.page-main__btn-prev {
  width: 71px;
  height: 59px;
  padding: 0;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: solid 5px #efefef;
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.page-main__btn-next {
  width: 71px;
  height: 59px;
  margin-left: -4px;
  padding: 0;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: solid 5px #efefef;
  border-left: solid 1px #efefef;
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.page-main__btn-next:hover,
.page-main__btn-prev:hover {
  background: #777;
}

.page-main__products-list {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
}

.page-main__products-item {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin-right: 47px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background: #cccccc;
  position: relative;
}

.page-main__products-item:nth-child(1) {
  background: red;
}

.page-main__products-item:nth-child(2) {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="page-main__block-products">
  <div class="page-main__controls">
    <button class="page-main__btn-prev">
      <span class="visually-hidden">Назад</span>
    </button>
    <button class="page-main__btn-next">
      <span class="visually-hidden">Вперёд</span>
    </button>
  </div>
  <ul class="page-main__products-list">
    <li class="page-main__products-item item-dragon">
      <span class="visually-hidden"></span>
    </li>
    <li class="page-main__products-item item-fence">
      <span class="visually-hidden"></span>
    </li>
    <li class="page-main__products-item item-chair">
      <span class="visually-hidden"></span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: https://codepen.io/dfitzy/pen/xZqGVo

Comment: Ммммм, не много не то. Но спасибо! Тут нужно что бы карточки менялись местами, кликнули вперёд, 1 карточка уходит в конец а за ней 2 уже показывается и дальше процесс повторяется. 
Но все 3 карточки должны быть видны, просто по клику продвигаются вперед/назад. Процесс похожий на слайдер но я 2 день ломаю голову и не могу сообразить как это делается...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение в лоб: в одном случае брать первый элемент и добавлять его в конец родителя с помощью метода [`appendChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild), в другом - брать последний элемент и вставлять его перед первым с помощью метода [`insertBefore`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/insertBefore)

Например:

```js
var ul = document.querySelector('.page-main__products-list');
document.querySelector('.page-main__btn-next').addEventListener('click', function() {
  ul.insertBefore(ul.lastElementChild, ul.firstElementChild);
});
document.querySelector('.page-main__btn-prev').addEventListener('click', function() {
  ul.appendChild(ul.firstElementChild);
});
```

```css
.page-main__block-products {
  margin: 0 0 0 0;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  display: flex;
}

.page-main__controls {
  width: 142px;
  height: 59px;
  margin-top: 40px;
  margin-right: 30px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0px 10px 46px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.page-main__btn-prev {
  width: 71px;
  height: 59px;
  padding: 0;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: solid 5px #efefef;
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.page-main__btn-next {
  width: 71px;
  height: 59px;
  margin-left: -4px;
  padding: 0;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: solid 5px #efefef;
  border-left: solid 1px #efefef;
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.page-main__btn-next:hover,
.page-main__btn-prev:hover {
  background: #777;
}

.page-main__products-list {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
}

.page-main__products-item {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin-right: 47px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background: #cccccc;
  position: relative;
}

.page-main__products-item.item-dragon {
  background: red;
}

.page-main__products-item.item-fence {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="page-main__block-products">
  <div class="page-main__controls">
    <button class="page-main__btn-prev">
      <span class="visually-hidden">Назад</span>
    </button>
    <button class="page-main__btn-next">
      <span class="visually-hidden">Вперёд</span>
    </button>
  </div>
  <ul class="page-main__products-list">
    <li class="page-main__products-item item-dragon">
      <span class="visually-hidden">1</span>
    </li>
    <li class="page-main__products-item item-fence">
      <span class="visually-hidden">2</span>
    </li>
    <li class="page-main__products-item item-chair">
      <span class="visually-hidden">3</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Вот спасибо вам, от души как говорится!